# Software for simulating mouse click at a specific position with shortcut key?

Tags: windows-7, simulation, mouse, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm looking for a software which lets me simulate left mouse click at specific positions by pressing custom shortcut keys.

And I also need to create multiple simulations. For example, I would like to press the A key to simulate left mouse click at a position, and to press the B key to simulate left mouse click at another position, ... and so on.

I was using a software called "Auto Mouse Click" (by MurGee.com) to do this. But that software isn't free and my trial duration has expired.

Note: I of course would want to purchase the software I mentioned. But due to various reasons, I'm being unable to do that presently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more general tool that can do the job would be [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/). But for a simpler, more mouse-only oriented tool, you can try [Auto Mouse Click Generator](https://sourceforge.net/projects/superclick/)

Both are free and both will do the job.

Comment: Thanks. But my Avast is considering AutoHotKey as malware and does not let me download it. Auto Mouse Click Generator seems to only allow one simulation at a time.

Comment: Autohotkey is legit, but make your own judgement. You should be able to tell Avast to whitelist the download. However, I would not attempt to download the software from anywhere else - there is always the potential of downloading a doctored, infected file.