# On a Windows PC, is there a software that I can automate a left down mouse-click at a specific location using a keyboard shortcut

Tags: windows, gratis, automation, mouse, keyboard-shortcuts

I have checked out the recommendations of this [page](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/42265/software-for-simulating-mouse-click-at-a-specific-position-with-shortcut-key). However, I've found that "AutoHotKey" has a pretty steep learning curve and "Auto Mouse Click Generator" does not have the functionality I want. Is there a free software that I can record / specify a left mouse at a specific X-Y location on the screen via a shortcut (i.e., SHIFT + E).

What I like to do is to combine human manual mouse click and use the pre-recorded shortcuts to automate the other part. For example, I like to create a short-cut to do a left mouse click at X=150, Y=150 as SHIFT + E.

Then I can manually click where I want on a screen > then SHIFT + E > then some other human input > then SHIFT + E.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this task using NirCmd by NirSoft.  It is generously provided as gratis software from Nir Sofer, the author.  It is *not* currently open-source, but that was not mentioned as a requirement.

You can set the cursor position using the `setcursor [X] [Y]` command.  From the documentation:

> Set the position of mouse cursor. The [X] and [Y] parameters specifies the desired cursor position.
> Example:
> setcursor 100 50

If you want to set the position relative to the active window, you can instead use the `setcursorwin [X] [Y]` command.  From the documentation:

> Set the position of mouse cursor, relative to the top-left corner of the active window. The [X] and [Y] parameters specifies the desired cursor position.
> Example:
> setcursor 100 50

You can then perform a primary-button mouse-click by using the command `sendmouse click`.

Because you will be performing multiple commands, create a small script file with the commands, which is just a basic simple text file.

Then you can call all the commands at once using NirCmd's `script` functionality.  From the documentation:

> script [Script File]
> This command allows you to execute a sequence of commands stored inside the file specified in [Script File] parameter.

To tie it all together, you can then create a shortcut with any hotkey to your command script using the `cmdshortcutkey` command. It has the syntax:

> cmdshortcutkey [folder] [shortcut title] [hot key] [command]

The NirCmd help file will be your friend and guide to help you with any additional details.

***Links for you:***

NirCmd Home Page: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html
NirCmd 32-bit (with .chm help file) download: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.zip
NirCmd 64-bit (with .chm help file) download: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd-x64.zip
NirCmd Online Help File: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd2.html#using
NirSoft Home Page: https://www.nirsoft.net/
NirLauncher Home Page (includes NirCmd and over 200 other free quality tools): https://launcher.nirsoft.net/downloads/index.html

Comment: Thanks, but I try `nircmd setcursor 1650 962 sendmouse click`, it sends the mouse to the right location, but doesn't actually click.

Comment: I am able to create a shortcut key, but after I execute the shortcut, it takes more than one second for the mouse starts jumping to the desired location. Is this much lag normal? Is there a way to reduce the latency?

Comment: To sequence more than one command after another, you either need to use the NirCmd's `script` functionality (very simple: just create a text file with all the commands), or run a separate instance of NirCmd with each command (it's not possible to chain them on a single command line as you've done, although that would be a great feature!).

Comment: Regarding lag, one second seems unusually long.  Try running NirCmd directly from the command line (without a shortcut key) to see if there is any lag.  Even on a fairly slow machine, running a NirCmd command should be almost instantaneous.

Comment: Thanks, regarding the lag, it is not an uncommon problem. And I found the temporary solution here (https://superuser.com/questions/426947/slow-windows-desktop-keyboard-shortcuts) by ending the "Application Frame Host" from my active apps.

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad to help.  Thank you for the link to the lag Q/A.  I actually have never experienced it, but as you determined, others certainly have.  I actually had that Q/A bookmarked just in case it ever happened to me, but I completely forgot about it, as I bookmarked it almost a decade ago!